# How to create a dictionary list type property for document type in Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco

I am quite new to Umbraco. I want to create a new property in my document type. This property is a list which contains items like dictionary type which has a key and a value. User can select multiple of these. For example

My document type is "Product", The property I want to create is "Related Items". Each related item will have an name & a url.

Can someone please give me an idea how to do this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default data types of Umbraco for it: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/default-datatypes (The wiki doesn't seem updated, but an the ultimate picker will get you the result you need, for example) You can do this in the developer section, create a new one from the defaults and add it to your document type afterwards.

You can also build a custom one, wich is becoming more and more easy, but the approach of doing it is now different in the new umbraco 7 version. Which version are you using?